# Traverse Through Space-separated String

Tags: awk, string

So I ran `ips=$(arp | awk '{print $1}')` to save all the IP addresses retrieved from the `arp` command into a variable, `ips`. `echo` of `ips` gives me `Address 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.101 192.168.10.1`. I am assuming that `Address 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.101 192.168.10.1` is saved as  string in the `ips` variable. What I want is a way to loop through the variable `ips` and maybe save the one in a variable, `ip`, do something with it, and move to next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space is the default field separator so a simple `for` loop can handle this without issue. Be very careful when doing this because you can [end up with unexpected results very easily doing these types of loops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
ips=$(arp | awk '{print $1}')
for ip in $ips
do
     #Work here
     echo IP: $ip
done
```